# Using Generics with a Parent/Child entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, business-objects

I have a entity A and a entity B. B Inherits from A and is a superset of A. I have a method on the .ascx that currently loads control properties and binds the data from the A entity. I would like to expand the method to include B. I think I would need to create an entity that contains all of the fields from both and then cast the A or B to the Combined entity type. Anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: A `Claim` is a `Policy`? That doesn't seem right to me. Rethink your model.

Comment: For this application yes a claim is defined as all properties of the policy and an additional set of data related to the claim only.

Comment: You're talking from a technical perspective, I'm talking from a conceptual perspective. I make a `Claim` on my `Policy`, but a `Claim` is not a `Policy`.

Comment: Then wouldn't it be better to have the claim reference the policy somehow, i.e. model the relationship with aggregation rather than inheritance?

Comment: just a little tip: try give some real code. We are programmers so some source is worth more than even a picture ;)

Comment: It's not really that kind of relationship. I know that a policy can have multiple claims. But this is not that kind of implementation. These are Policy and Claim Adjustments from a datawarehouse db. The data I get back from the SP's for policy is what I get back for Claim with a superset of data for claim. I could put Claim as a property of Policy and only use claim when I need it. But then when I want to retrieve a Claim Adjustment I would need to load a Policy Adjustment entity. That is not what I am looking for. I want to keep the data retrieval duties segregated to their types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, I would avoid the casting and instead create a `BindB(B b)` method that passes the object to the existing `Bind(A a)` method (no cast required thanks to morphism), then performs the additional binding for the B properties.  The method you are suggesting will require a cast to the "super-object" before calling, only to operate conditionally on data you just hid (the actual type of the object).  Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I ended up rethinking the hierarchy of the entities and simplified them allowing w proper implementation. Thanks for the response